# Simple C++ Code which gives me a wrong count of loops. Need help to correct it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

The issue is in do loop in the third line. I've tried tries++ and ++tries but, it returns as the tries as 01 when i executed the program. I need help to get the right number of loop counts.

```
// Guess My Number
// The classic number guessing game

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));  //seed random number generator

int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;  // random number between 1 and 100
int tries = 0;
int guess;

cout << "\tWelcome to Guess My Number\n\n";

do
{
    cout << "Enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    ++tries;

    if (guess > secretNumber)
    {
        cout << "Too high!\n\n";
    }
    else if (guess < secretNumber)
    {
        cout << "Too low!\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";
    }

} while (guess != secretNumber);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you wrote `tries += tries;` in the code snippet

Comment: Yes. But, still the result is the same. Doesn't matter the loop run 50 times the tries value is returned as 01 every time I run.

Comment: Works for me (with the `++tries` edit).  Are you sure you're successfully recompiling after making the change?

Comment: http://ideone.com/xZly1f It just works fine with `tries++`.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just guessing it in one try every time?

Comment: When you try to increment your tries variable inside your do-while loop, because it is initialized to 0, you are doing 0+=0, which I don't think it what you want to be doing...Try doing tries+=1 instead and see if that fixes it

Comment: It's also kind of strange that you say (several times) that the program prints `01` - sending the `int` variable `tries` to `cout` shouldn't display a leading zero (unless other formatting expressions or manipulators are used). I believe you're not actually running the program you think you're running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
tries += tries;
```

That just adds `0` to itself over and over.

I think you are trying to do `tries++;`

**Edit:** Your edit indicates that you have tried `tries++` and `++tries` but are still having problems. Either of those will work, so you are having some other problem. Most likely, you are not recompiling successfully. Be sure you have recompiled the modified code!

Comment: I tried it but, it still returns 01 all the time regardless of the number of loops it run.

Comment: @DilshanDeZoysa Something else is going on. Please be sure you have recompiled before testing again.